# QTcpServer - Unsupported Socket Operation on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt

I am trying to start a server on Android using QTcpServer with Qt 5.3.1 but the server does not start and I get "Unsupported Socket Operation". It works fine on Windows.

Code below:

```
void StartListening()
{
   QHostAddress hostAddress;
   hostAddress.setAddress(QString("localhost"));

   hostAddress.toIPv4Address();
   quint16 portNumber = 9878;

   server->setMaxPendingConnections(1);
   server->setProxy(QNetworkProxy::NoProxy);

   if (server->listen(hostAddress, portNumber))
   {
       // Ok
   }
   else
   {
     Debug("Server did not start. " + server->errorString());
   }
}
```

server->errorString() returns "**Unsupported Socket Operation** when it runs on Android

Isn't this supported by Qt Android or am I doing something wrong?

Thx

Comment: Do you have the Internet permission on the manifest file?

Comment: Yes I do have internet permission in the file but I keep getting the error. The server does not start and I get that message.

Comment: According to http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtcpserver.html QTcpServer is supported on Android

Answer (score 1):

OK! I worked it out.

The problem is with this line:

```
 hostAddress.setAddress(QString("localhost"));
```

If I replace "**localhost**" with "**127.0.0.1**", the server starts fine but no one outside the "device the server is running on" can connect to it. This  means, let's say your network is using **192.168.1.xx** and your Android device has the following IP address: **192.168.1.2**. If you start the server with "**127.0.0.1**" on your Android device which has an IP address: "**192.168.1.2**" and then using your PC with an IP address **192.168.1.3** you do **telnet 192.168.1.2 9878** it will fail to connect!

So then I decided to start the server by specifying the IP address of the Android device: **192.168.1.2**

```
 hostAddress.setAddress(QString("192.168.1.2"));
```

Voila! That works too! The server starts and I can connect from outside the device! For example if I do **telnet 192.168.1.2 9878** from my PC while the server is started on Android, it connects! So all I need to do now is replace the hard coded IP address with the actual IP address of the device! I think QNetworkInterface::allInterfaces() or something like that will give me the ability to get the default IP address.

So just use the actual IP address of the network card rather than localhost or 127.0.0.1 and all should be Ok. All working now.

Comment: Just for completeness sake: "0.0.0.0" shouldalso work as "universal ipv4" address. This will bind the socket too all local ipv4 addresses, makeing it accessible through all ipv4 interfaces